# Direct Use of Function Pointers of a member function

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I am little confused about the usage of function pointers here. 
I have a method called gc() defined like this:

```
static const float *gc( int i)
{
    return( &H[ BufSize*i ] );
}
```

Where this H is a float pointer. What I have done now is made both these (H and gc()) to be a member of a class like this:

```
class named
{
float* H;
static const float *gc( int i)
    {
        return( &H[ BufSize*i ] );
    }

int newMethod()
{   
int newd = external_function(const float* (gc*)(int), <other-parameters>);
return newd;
}
};
```

However as both H and gc() are members now, the syntax doesn't change but now I am confused how to call this (member) function pointer from an external function, like this :

```
int external_function(const float* (gc*)(int), <other-parameters>);
```

This is actually an external function and I am calling it from inside the class. So since gc and H are already the members of the class, this shouldn't produce any errors. Am I right in my reasoning?

P.S.It is also not clear that how such an implementation can be right without passing a reference to the given class.

Comment: I think H should be static since you are referencing it in a static manner.
As for calling a function pointer, just use the variable name for the pointer as a function call.
`varName( 123);`

Comment: The line `external_function(const float* (gc*)(int), <other-parameters>);` looks like a declaration; do I understand correctly that you mean it to be a _call_? Then it would be `external_function(gc, <other-parameters>);` as in need suggested.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Sorry. I have made the changes. Can you see them again, please?

Comment: This is not safe, member functions have an implict `this` parameter that the external function knows nothing about I would suggest using [`std::mem_fn`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) if you intend to pass this to another function, that way you're passing the instance WITH the function parameter explicitly.

Comment: @Mgetz I get your point. So is this line better then? `int newd = external_function(const float* ((this->gc)*)(int), <other-parameters>);` and in the implementation of gc, I replace `H` with `this->H` ?

Comment: @AdityaKumarPraharaj now that the function is `static` my comment is irrelevant.. but I'll leave it as a warning, passing member functions around must be done VERY carefully. However if the function is `static` it won't be able to access `H`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a complete example with a "normal" function in addition to a static member function:

```
void external_function(const float* (*f)(int)){ cout << *(f(3)) << endl; }

// declaration of a "normal" function with the same signature as gc; 
// (declaring it here is needed because we refer to it in named::newMethod(),
const float *globally_visible_func(int i2);

class named
{
public: // need to make H accessible for externalgc
    static float H[];
private:
    static const float *gc( int i)
    {
        cout << "static function named::gc, arg was " << i << endl;
        return( &H[i] );
    }
public:
    int newMethod()
    {
        H[3] = 123;

        // Use a pointer to the static member function gc as argument
        external_function(gc);

        // now use a pointer to a "normal" function as argument. There
        // is no difference.
        external_function(globally_visible_func);
    }
};

// A pointer to this "normal" function is used as argument above
const float *globally_visible_func(int i2) 
{
    cout << "globally_visible_func, arg was " << i2 << endl;
    return named::H + i2;
}

float named::H[100];  // must define (i.e. create and initialize) static data member

int main()
{
    named n;
    n.newMethod();
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the detailed explanation. BTW, can you explain how the reference of the class passes to that in-class call of external_function?

Comment: It doesn't ;-). No, seriously. A static member function is (at least in any practical respect) a plain old normal function; except that its name needs to be prefixed with the class name, as if it were in a namespace, and access restrictions like "private" apply. There is no object involved. That's the reason why a static member function can not directly access normal members of a class (for which object?), but only static members which are equally not bound to any object.

Comment: I added another "normal" function in the example to show that there is no difference.